# YouTube API v3 is not responding in JSON with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, youtube-api, alamofire, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube API v3 to get search results on a query with Alamofire. This is my code:

```
Alamofire.request(makeURL(query: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=apple&key=AIzaSyAbwfyC36pq1WoaGOkdx7m8cLMh8kMQRGE"), method: .get, parameters: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
    print(response.result.value)     
}
```

**What I was expecting:**
The API response was meant to be in JSON.

**What actually happens:**
It comes out not as JSON but something else.

How can I get the response as JSON?

Comment: your URL seems to be Incorrect....

Comment: what part is incorrect?

Comment: {
error: {
errors: [
{
domain: "youtube.part",
reason: "unknownPart",
message: "part",
locationType: "parameter",
location: "part"
}
],
code: 400,
message: "part"
}
}

Comment: This is the response that you are getting from youtube API..l and that is in JSON Format

Comment: are you doing this on Alamofire in Swift?

Comment: No, I have just copied your URL from your Code and paste into Browser...

Comment: shoot, there was a mistake in the code from when I put it on stack overflow, try now

Comment: Yes now, Your API URL works perfectly...

Comment: Now let me try.

Comment: Hi, it worked successfully :)

Comment: But it doesn’t come out as JSON tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=apple&key=AIzaSyAbwfyC36pq1WoaGOkdx7m8cLMh8kMQRGE").responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
        }
```

And the Result is in JSON Format

```
SUCCESS: {
    etag = "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/XGmvZBQRhfhL_NmuaAj4nOXRYgE\"";
    items =     (
                {
            etag = "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/3wIsul9XoecWMttT8KgkS-NJVsY\"";
            id =             {
                kind = "youtube#video";
                videoId = hq3yfQnllfQ;
            };
            kind = "youtube#searchResult";
            snippet =             {
                channelId = "UCBnZ16ahKA2DZ_T5W0FPUXg";
                channelTitle = "ChuChu TV Nursery Rhymes & Kids Songs";
                description = "ABC \"Phonics\" song. This animated phonics song will help children learn the sounds of the letters in the English alphabet. This colorful phonics song also ...";
                liveBroadcastContent = none;
                publishedAt = "2014-03-06T20:57:50.000Z";
                thumbnails =                 {
                    default =                     {
                        height = 90;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hq3yfQnllfQ/default.jpg";
                        width = 120;
                    };
                    high =                     {
                        height = 360;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hq3yfQnllfQ/hqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 480;
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        height = 180;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hq3yfQnllfQ/mqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 320;
                    };
                };
                title = "Phonics Song with TWO Words - A For Apple - ABC Alphabet Songs with Sounds for Children";
            };
        },
                {
            etag = "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/deVTTMRJ83lNlVBvgZ-IAmhGW74\"";
            id =             {
                channelId = "UCE_M8A5yxnLfW0KghEeajjw";
                kind = "youtube#channel";
            };
            kind = "youtube#searchResult";
            snippet =             {
                channelId = "UCE_M8A5yxnLfW0KghEeajjw";
                channelTitle = Apple;
                description = "Apple revolutionized personal technology with the introduction of the Macintosh in 1984. Today, Apple leads the world in innovation with iPhone, iPad, Mac, ...";
                liveBroadcastContent = none;
                publishedAt = "2005-06-22T05:12:23.000Z";
                thumbnails =                 {
                    default =                     {
                        url = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-KdgJnz1HIdQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4vVN7slJqj4/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg";
                    };
                    high =                     {
                        url = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-KdgJnz1HIdQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4vVN7slJqj4/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg";
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        url = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-KdgJnz1HIdQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4vVN7slJqj4/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg";
                    };
                };
                title = Apple;
            };
        },
                {
            etag = "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/VlSh6Sn6qQgT1FNtsvJ9sUkw8ag\"";
            id =             {
                kind = "youtube#video";
                videoId = hXxsTy74Qsg;
            };
            kind = "youtube#searchResult";
            snippet =             {
                channelId = "UCS83hSDCu-fVLvRLQ1aiktQ";
                channelTitle = "Jolly Toy Art";
                description = "Hi guys~ It's Yuna. Let's draw and color Apple & cutlery set ! Don't forget to Subscribe & Like drawing and coloring Glitter closet for kids and toddlers. Thanks For ...";
                liveBroadcastContent = none;
                publishedAt = "2019-02-01T03:00:02.000Z";
                thumbnails =                 {
                    default =                     {
                        height = 90;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hXxsTy74Qsg/default.jpg";
                        width = 120;
                    };
                    high =                     {
                        height = 360;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hXxsTy74Qsg/hqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 480;
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        height = 180;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hXxsTy74Qsg/mqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 320;
                    };
                };
                title = "Glitter Apple cutlery set coloring and drawing for Kids, Toddlers | Jolly Toy Art \U2606";
            };
        },
                {
            etag = "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/UnM3fnWWNiSH-CV6p2o8URgd2bI\"";
            id =             {
                kind = "youtube#video";
                videoId = aAUGkuVEbq8;
            };
            kind = "youtube#searchResult";
            snippet =             {
                channelId = UCqSmraORoX9ZE8s7nfEdcuA;
                channelTitle = "Life is Fabulous";
                description = "Apple & Caterpillar Drawing For Kids Thanks for watching!";
                liveBroadcastContent = none;
                publishedAt = "2018-06-08T21:40:21.000Z";
                thumbnails =                 {
                    default =                     {
                        height = 90;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aAUGkuVEbq8/default.jpg";
                        width = 120;
                    };
                    high =                     {
                        height = 360;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aAUGkuVEbq8/hqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 480;
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        height = 180;

                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aAUGkuVEbq8/mqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 320;
                    };
                };
                title = "Apple &amp; Caterpillar Drawing For Kids";
            };
        },
                {
            etag = "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/2jayGhnvbSrxvPCW6IM3M1Zlnws\"";
            id =             {
                kind = "youtube#video";
                videoId = Zc7xmtDkLCE;
            };
            kind = "youtube#searchResult";
            snippet =             {
                channelId = "UCj34AOIMl_k1fF7hcBkD_dw";
                channelTitle = EverythingApplePro;
                description = "Why the iPhone 11 lens is so big! iOS 13 passport support, Mini LED future, original Apple phone prototype & more Apple leaks & news. Last Apple leaks.";
                liveBroadcastContent = none;
                publishedAt = "2019-04-15T17:22:34.000Z";
                thumbnails =                 {

                    default =                     {
                        height = 90;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zc7xmtDkLCE/default.jpg";
                        width = 120;
                    };
                    high =                     {
                        height = 360;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zc7xmtDkLCE/hqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 480;
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        height = 180;
                        url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zc7xmtDkLCE/mqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 320;
                    };
                };
                title = "iPhone 11 Lens Explained + Apples Future Tech!";
            };
        }
    );
    kind = "youtube#searchListResponse";
    nextPageToken = CAUQAA;
    pageInfo =     {
        resultsPerPage = 5;
        totalResults = 1000000;
    };
    regionCode = PK;
}
```

Comment: All the online json formatters don’t recognise that as json

Comment: Brother just Forget about Online JSON Validator... This is in JSON Format... The reason is ONLINE Validator are not recognizing because they are not much ACCURATE... Sometimes you don't need to believe on it... Just go ahead and Done your Task...

Comment: I had been already worked with Youtube API. I assure you this will work. RESPONSEJSON in Alamofire, its duty to give RESULTS in JSON.

Comment: But usually I can subscript, how can I do that for this?

Comment: like when you do json[“items”] to get further inside the json to get the data

Comment: I had done like this to get JSON data from API... I have UPDATED my answer.. Hope so you now will understand.

Comment: So now i'm going to remove last Part of Answer...  Hope so now you have understand the problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191955/discussion-between-callum-and-mr-ahtazaz).

Comment: In your Youtube API response. you are getting both Video ID & Channel ID. That's why you causing Error...

Comment: In the first Item, you are getting VideoId But in the second item, you are getting CHannel ID...